# How can I download an image from an AWS bucket to generate a PDF from, using FPDF?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-s3

I have a FPDF object like this:

```
import fpdf

pdf = FPDF()

#Cover page
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.cell(175, 10, 'TEST - report',0,1,'C')
```

I'm trying to use a `.png` file from AWS S3 bucket directly to generate a PDF, like so:

```
pdf.image(bucket_folder_name + '/' + file_name + '.png')
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is the issue?

Comment: download the file first then specify the path

Comment: the point is that I want to upload file directly from S3 bucket

Comment: you can't, you need to download it first

Comment: an S3 bucket is not your local folder for you to be able to just upload it directly - download the object first and then upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use files from an S3 bucket, you need to download them first - an S3 bucket is not like a local folder for you to be able to provide a path and use the file.

Download the file first using [`download_file`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) and then pass the filename to `pdf.image(...)`.

The `download_file` method has the following parameters:

```
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

Something like this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
...

filename_with_extension = file_name + '.png';
outputPath = '/tmp/' + filename_with_extension;

s3.download_file(bucket_folder_name, filename_with_extension, outputPath)

pdf.image(outputPath)
```

---

**Important note**: you **must** write to the `/tmp` directory as that is the only available file system that AWS permits you to write to (and read from).

Any other path will result in a `[Errno 13] Permission denied` error to indicate this.

Per [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/):

> You can configure each Lambda function with its own ephemeral storage between 512MB and 10,240MB, in 1MB increments. The ephemeral storage is available in each function’s /tmp directory.

Comment: Ok, I did it and response looks good, but I still get an error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, when I run pdf.image("test.png"), where "test.png" is my raw filename. Any ideas? :(

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: Let me add a complete answer as I was typing this on my phone yesterday - one sec

Comment: @sdom Try the updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Right now I have an issue with proper downloading file, I get: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'lastAvailPic.png.137BbD88'.. I'll try to figure it out first. But these are new things for me, I feel like a blind hah

Comment: Sorry, I missed out something - one sec! I'm trying to multi task lol

Comment: That should work, third time's the charm :) @sdom

Comment: Hurray, it works! You made my day, many thanks :)

Comment: More than welcome, enjoy using AWS :)